# Twilio Programmable video - Calling .disable() on LocalVideoTrack doesn't stop it being transmitted

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, twilio, videochat

I am trying to allow my users to decrease bandwidth usage if their call is choppy by disabling video. The documentation says:

"Mute or Pause a Single Media Track

To control the muted/unmuted or the paused/unpaused state of a single LocalAudioTrack of LocalVideoTrack, you can use the LocalTrack#enable and LocalTrack#disable methods.
"

However when I use this, the local media element goes black (ie it stops rendering) but the remote stream (open in a different window) still recieves video. The code I am using is included below.

```
createLocalVideoTrack().then(track => {
            var localMediaContainer = document.getElementById(self.local_vid_id);
            var title = document.createElement('span')
            title.innerText = "Me";
            localMediaContainer.appendChild(title);
            var videoIcon = document.createElement('span')
            videoIcon.className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video';
            videoIcon.title = 'Disable Video';
            videoIcon.videoTrack = track;
            videoIcon.onclick = (event) => {
                if (event.target.videoTrack.isEnabled) {
                    event.target.videoTrack.disable();
                    event.target.title = 'Enable Video';
                } else {
                    event.target.videoTrack.enable();
                    event.target.title = 'Disable Video';
                }
            }
            localMediaContainer.appendChild(videoIcon);
            localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
        });
```

Has anyone else come across this, is there a simple fix?

Comment: Hello, you shouldn't still be able to see the video on the remote stream. Could you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and describe this issue so that the Video team can investigate it? Thanks.

Comment: @philnash I managed to find the documented way to do it is by calling `removeTrack`. There wasn't any way to create a new video track (re enable it) without totally reconnecting to the room, so I think that could be something to talk to the team about.

Comment: Hey, yeah, removing the track completely removes the track from the connection and requires a full reconnection to start again. Disabling it should not incur that cost, but if it's not working that's of no use! I have made the team aware of this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here but hopefully others will find it useful.

You need to remove the videoTrack to stop it being sent.
The final version of the code I used is

```
videoIcon.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.videoTrack){
    self.room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach( (track) => {
      self.room.localParticipant.removeTrack(track,true);
    })
    trackRemoved(event.target.videoTrack);
    event.target.videoTrack.stop();
    event.target.title = 'Enable Video';
    event.target.videoTrack = undefined;
  } else {
    // Totally reconnect to the room
    self.stop();
    self.reconnect();
    self.startPreview();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The potential issue is that most probably you don't use that newly created local tracks when calling the `connect(token, options)` function. So when you don't specify `tracks` in the [options](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.6.1/docs/global.html#ConnectOptions), it's going to create new local tracks with different ids. So you see your local video through the local video track which you have created by `createLocalVideoTrack()` or `createLocalTracks()` functions and send video data to the remote participant through completely different local video track which have been created during the `connect()` function.

So in order to overcome with this issue you should specify the created tracks in the option, in order to use the same tracks or get the tracks which have been created from the connect()function. After that if you call `disable()` function it will mute in both sides of the conversation.

**Option 1 - Specifying tracks.**

```js
const { connect, createLocalTracks } = require('twilio-video');

createLocalTracks({
  audio: true,
  video: true
}).then(localTracks => {
  return connect('$TOKEN', {
    name: 'my-room-name',
    tracks: localTracks
  });
}).then(room => {
  console.log('Connected to Room:', room.name);
  localTracks.forEach((track)=>{
     // hide camera after 5 seconds
     if(track.kind === 'video'){
       setTimeout(()=>{
         track.disable();
       } ,5000)  
     }
  }) 
});
```

**Option 1 - Using the tracks created from the connection**

```js
Twilio.Video.connect('$TOKEN', {name:'my-new-room'}).then(function(room) {
  console.log('Successfully joined a Room: ', room);
  room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach((track)=>{
     // hide camera after 5 seconds
     if(track.kind === 'video'){
       setTimeout(()=>{
         track.disable();
       } ,5000)  
     }
  });
  room.on('participantConnected', function(participant) {
    console.log('A remote Participant connected: ', participant);
  })
}, function(error) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to Room: ' +  error.message);
});
```