# Twilio track disable not working as expected

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I want to mute my self in a twilio video app. But the problem is that when I use the method mentioned in the documentation

```
room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach((publication) => {
                publication.track.disable();
            });
```

This hides the video on my screen, but the remote participants can still see my video. Same happens for audio too. When I tried to debug, the tracks received on the remote participant side still have enabled true. How should I properly mute/turn off my video so that it is reflected on remote participant

Comment: You should be able to listen to [the "disabled" event on remote video tracks](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.7.0/docs/RemoteVideoTrack.html#event:disabled__anchor) which will tell the other participants that the video has been paused. You can use that event to hide the video element. But the `disable()` method should do what you expect. Are there any errors thrown in developer tools?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Any new on this?

Comment: @philnash I think if I disable my video, that means I don't want it streamed to anybody. I don't want my privacy contingent on other users' browsers behaving honestly.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861869/twilio-programmable-video-calling-disable-on-localvideotrack-doesnt-stop-i